# どうすればdocument.querySelectorAllの結果をノードに変換できますか？

Tags: javascript

`document.quetySeletorall`で同じクラス名を持つ要素の集合を受け取ってそれに対してDOM操作を行いたいです。
しかし、`document.querySelectorAll`はいわば配列もどきみたいな形で結果を受け取るようなので`Top`がDOMノードではないので使えないとエラー出てきます。

配列であればそのまま使えますが、`Top`は配列そのものではない、つまりDOMノードになっていないのでこのままでは利用できずにDOMノードに変換する必要があると聞きます。

Q1 どんな処理をすると`Top`をDOMノードに変換できるのでしょうか？

Q2 この`Top`は配列とはどう違うのでしょうか？

```js
var Top = document.querySelectorAll('.top');

document.querySelector('#js').addEventListener('click', function() {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(Top,function(x){
        x.parentNode.insertBefore(Top, x);
    });
});
```

Comment: どういう状況なのかさっぱりわかりません。現状のコードを提示してください。

Comment: https://codepen.io/webpagecodepen/pen/oqyaKBこちらに一部抜粋しました。

Comment: 正確なエラーメッセージもあると良いと思います。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`querySelectorAll()` の戻り値は `NodeList` という型です。

https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-parentnode

> `[NewObject] NodeList querySelectorAll(DOMString selectors);`

https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#nodelist

```
interface NodeList {
  getter Node? item(unsigned long index);
  readonly attribute unsigned long length;
  iterable<Node>;
};
```

おっしゃる通り配列ではありません。`length` プロパティと index getter があるので、配列のように `for` でループして各要素にアクセスすることができます。

```
var top = document.querySelectorAll('.top');
for (var i = 0; i < top.length; ++i) {
  var node = top[i]; // これが Node 型
  ...
}

for (var node of document.querySelectorAll('.top')) {
  ... // node が Node 型
}
```

また、最近のブラウザなら `forEach` もそのまま使えます。

```
document.querySelectorAll('.top').forEach(function(node) {
  ... // node が Node 型
});
```

`Node` ではないので、`NodeList` をそのまま `insertBefore()` の引数にはできません。

もし `'.top'` にマッチする要素が１つだけと決まっているなら、`querySelectorAll('.top')[0]` とするか `querySelector('.top')` で
ノードが手に入ります。

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('.top')
この書き方でこのクラス名の要素を取得した時だけNodeとして取得できず、NodeListというNodeもどき？で取得してしまい、
Nodeもどきだとこの要素をDOM操作したいできないのですね。

なぜこの書き方だとNodeListという一般的な形で取得ができないのでしょうか？

また、Allを入れないとNodeListという形で取得できるようですが今回は同じクラス名の要素が複数あります。
NodeもどきをNodeListに変換する方法はないのでしょうか？

Comment: NodeListはNodeもどきではなく配列もどきだと思ってください。Nodeを得る方法は示したつもりですが、何がわかりませんか。

Comment: NodeListで使えるのは、itemメソッドとlengthプロパティしか使えないようなのでこれ以外のメソッドは利用不可能なようですね。
なぜこんな不便な形で取得してしまうのでしょうか

Comment: 配列もどきなんですね。また複数要素がある場合は下記のように利用すれば配列と同じように利用できるのですか？

Comment: ＞＞＞おっしゃる通り配列ではありません。length プロパティと index getter があるので、配列のように for でループして各要素にアクセスすることができます。

var top = document.querySelectorAll('.top');
for (var i = 0; i < top.length; ++i) {
  var node = top[i];
  ...
}

for (var node of document.querySelectorAll('.top')) {
  ...
}

また、最近のブラウザなら forEach もそのまま使えます。

document.querySelectorAll('.top').forEach(function(node) { ... });

Comment: 配列もどきの要素数を数えるlengthプロパティと index getter ？というもの二つだけ本物の配列と同じように利用可能なのですね。
これ以外のメソッドとプロパティは本物の配列でないのでほぼ一切利用不可能なのですね。
index getterというものが難しくてさっぱりわからないのですが、これはメソッドか何かですか？

Comment: また配列もどきは下記のようにインデックス番号順に何かを実行するという処理は本物の配列同様可能なのですね。
下記なら要素がちゃんと要素数分コンソールに表記されるはずなのですね。このようなこと以外は本物の配列のように行うことが不可能なのでしょうか？
これは本物の配列に変換することはできないのでしょうか？
allをつけるだけでなんでこんな面倒なもどきになってしまうのか全く理解できません。
var top = document.querySelectorAll('.top');
for (var i = 0; i < top.length; ++i) {
  var node = top[i]; // これが Node 型
  console.log(node);
}